# How to load images dynamically from server and display them

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have images stored on my server i.e. i have a directory on my server such as :
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

i need to load each of the image from the directory and display in on the following html :

```
<div class="image-set">
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/5.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/7.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/8.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/9.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/9.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/10.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/11.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/11.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/12.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/13.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/13.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
```

the img tags can be dynamically increased , can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: what do you mean by simple loop ? yes if you mean i need to display all images in a directory then i have to loop all of them

Comment: You do a loop that make a line of html for each image you have in your folder

Comment: so write some code to generate the html...

Comment: Get your images with [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) loop the result of that with [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), once you put them two together, if you have problems come back and ask again with the **code you have tried.** good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to scan the directory for all of the image files you want:

```
$imageFiles = [];
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';

// check folder exists
if (is_dir($uploadsDirectory))
{
    for (scandir($uploadsDirectory) as $file)
    {
        // include only desired file types
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'gif')
        {
            $imageFiles[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, providing you have set up an URL rewrite that links the url 'images/demopage/' to your directory where the images are stored (you can restrict it to only accept requests for images), you can do the following in your HTML template:

```
<div class="image-set">
    <?php
        foreach ($imageFiles as $image)
        {
            echo '<a class="example-image-link" href="images/demopage/' . $image . '" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close.">';
            echo '<img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/' . $image . '" alt="" />';
            echo '</a>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like to get image files. Use [glob](https://www.php.net/glob) function in php,

```
<div class="image-set">    
    <?php foreach (glob('images/demopage/*') as $filename) { ?>
        <img class="example-image" src="images/demopage/<?php echo basename($filename); ?>" alt=""/>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Something like that?

```
function getImageUrls($uploadsDirectory)
{
    $urls = array();
    foreach(scandir($uploadsDirectory) as $filename) {
        if($filename != '.' AND $filename != '..') {
            $pathinfo = pathinfo($filename);
            if(in_array($pathinfo['extension'], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
                $urls[] = $uploadsDirectory.$filename;
        }
    }
    return $urls;
}

// ----------------------------------


foreach(getImageUrls($uploadsDirectory) as $src) {
    echo '<a class="example-image-link" href="'.$src.'" data-lightbox="example-set"><img class="example-image" src="'.$src.'" alt=""/></a>'
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return from the function, and end the foreach.

Comment: nothing displayed as $src , means i am getting url array is null